# ssh tunneling only access

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Is it possible to configure ssh (on linux) to allow access for tunneling only? Ie user can setup tunnels but cannot get a shell/access files?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, just use `/bin/false` as shell and instruct the user to start the tunneling SSH process without executing any remote command (i.e. the `-N` flag for OpenSSH):

```
ssh -N -L 1234:target-host:5678 ssh-host
```

Comment: Um, if the user doesn't use `-N`, they have shell access. This *really* doesn't solve the problem and is dangerous.

Comment: @mlissner: No, if you have `/bin/false` as shell, you won't have shell access, as every login session will terminate immediately.

Comment: But will this prevent scp from working?

Comment: @Rémi Yes, but the question was asking for "only permit tunneling". If you want SCP then you can set up the account with the `scponly` shell instead of `false`. `scponly` will immediately exit if no SCP is initiated, but a user can still use `-N` to do port forwarding. Using `scponly` would allow tunnels and scp.

Answer (score 13):

In the user's .ssh/authorized_keys file, put something like the following:

```
permitopen="192.168.1.10:3306",permitopen="10.0.0.16:80",no-pty ssh-rsa AAAAB3N...
```

So, basically, you the controls would be in front of the user's ssh public key separated by a space.  In the example, connections using the specific public key will be allowed to do SSH port forwarding only to 192.168.1.10's MySQL server and 10.0.0.16's web server, and will not be assigned a shell (no-pty).  You're specifically asking about the "no-pty" option, but the others may also be useful if the user is only supposed to tunnel to specific servers.

Look at the man page for sshd for more options for the [authorized_keys file](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#SSHRC).

Note that the user's experience may look a little odd: when they ssh in, it will look like the session is hanging (as they are not getting a pty).  That's OK.  If the user has specified port forwarding with, for example, "-L3306:192.168.1.10:3306", the port forwarding will still be in effect.

In any case, give it a try.

Comment: **This is dangerous advice**; `no-pty` doesn't prevent shell access, it just doesn't give the shell a pty. It doesn't display the prompt (ie. "appears to hang"), but you can still give commands just fine. You need the `command="..."` option in `.ssh/authorized_keys` if you want to restrict shell access from there.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo is correct, but this is a start; you also must set shell to /usr/sbin/nologin or /bin/false in /etc/passwd to fully restrict the shell. I edited the above entry to reflect that, along with Aleksi's advice.

Answer (score 3):

Give the user a shell that only allows them to log out such as `/usr/local/bin/press_to_exit.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
read -n 1 -p "Press any key to exit" key
```

This way they can stay logged in as long as they want, with tunnels active, but not run any commands. `Ctrl-C` closes the connection.

Comment: I think that at least in theory, the user will be able to hit CTRL+C at the right moment (between lines 1 and 2) and end up with a full bash shell.

Answer (score 2):

Assign a shell that doesn't let the user log in.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "No interactive login available."
sleep 60
exit 0
```

would prevent them from getting a shell prompt, and give them a time-out of 60 seconds - if there's no connection active for 60 seconds then it will exit and thereby disconnect them completely (increase the number according to requirements).

They can't execute a remote command, either, because that shell won't let them.

Comment: Most linux installs already come with something for that. /sbin/nologin, or /bin/false or similar.

Comment: What would Ctrl-C do in the above example?

Comment: Arjan: Since the script is used as the shell, Ctrl-C would have the same effect as "`logout`" on a normal one.

Comment: I actually like earl's response, with the "-N" option, but if you want to give your user a helpful, friendly, informative message - and stop them leaving SSH connections all over the place - then a custom script is nice and clear about what it's doing.

Comment: @jrg This discussion is old and you might have changed your mind :) but IMHO it's dangerous to come out with handmade shell scripts. There is already  `/sbin/nologin`, which you can customize with an user-friendly message in `/etc/nologin.txt`.

Comment: There are some things that are dangerous in shell scripts, but this isn’t one of them (The original implementation of nologin - in BSD 4.4 - being a script is quite telling.) The main reason for my custom script suggestion was to support a tunnel being added after connection, not the message, hence why I personally still like Earl’s -N approach. These days I’d probably use a container with nothing else in it, as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
​##Create a new user

sudo useradd -m [user]

##Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Match User [user]
   #AllowTcpForwarding yes
   #X11Forwarding no
   #PermitTunnel no
   GatewayPorts yes ##Enable listening on 0.0.0.0
   AllowAgentForwarding no
   PermitOpen localhost:2888 ##specify port
   ForceCommand echo 'This account can only be used for Tunneling'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to provide the user who only may be tunneling, **without an interactive shell**, to set that shell in **/etc/passwd** to **/usr/bin/tunnel_shell**.

Just create the executable file **/usr/bin/tunnel_shell** with an **infinite loop**.

Additionally make use of the `AllowGroups` and `Match Group` option.

**Fully explained here:** http://blog.flowl.info/2011/ssh-tunnel-group-only-and-no-shell-please/

Comment: The user might be able to exit the executable somehow and escape a shell.  Are you perfectly confident that your executable won't allow to do this?

Comment: @dr01 To be honest, I am not sure if this is 100% secure. I guess when you exit the executable, the SSH session is quit, too. I will research this more and might comment again here.