# How to secure a a Linux user account so only SSH tunneling is possible?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh tunneling only access](https://serverfault.com/questions/56566/ssh-tunneling-only-access)

I'm thinking about using [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)'s java client to allow customers to access a virtual server. TightVNC supports tunneling the connection using SSH.

To make things more secure, I'd like to have the account used for this to only allow tunneling, but nothing else (ie. no shell). What is required to have tunneling work, but blocking everything else?

Comment: Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/56566/ssh-tunneling-only-access

Comment: Indeed, Gilles, you're right. Is there a way to mark it as a duplicate, or should I just delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

Set account shell to `/usr/sbin/nologin`