# How can I allow ssh tunneling/forwarding trough a machine without giving access to the intermediate machine

Tags: networking, ssh, ssh-tunnel, forwarding

Lets say i have a machine with a few virtual machines on them, how would i forward ssh connections to those virtual machines without giving access to the host machine? Is it possible to do so with only a single port exposed to the outside world? This would also apply to a machine, with some other machines behind it.

I would like to do the redirect based on which keys are used, or perhaps based on a flag set in the ssh command on the client.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH gateway with all config on the gateway?](https://serverfault.com/questions/952832/ssh-gateway-with-all-config-on-the-gateway)  or [ssh tunnel only acces](https://serverfault.com/q/56566/37681)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create user tunel and set his home shell to /bin/true.

This will allow `ssh -N -L local_port:ip_of_vm:port_of_vm tunel@your_ip` to work but if user try to get shell he will get just gracefull end of shell.

The second thing you should think of is if you can expose vm's to the internet so the second side have full access

Comment: Will this also protect against users trying to scp things to/from the host machine?

Comment: Yes it prevents it.